# Passing data through shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-4, tessellation

How it possible to pass data through shaders, when using vertex, tess. control, tess. evaluation, geometry and fragment shaders. I've tried using interface block this way.

```
//vertex shaders
out VS_OUT { ... } vs_out;
```

Than I wrote this code in tessellation control shader:

```
in VS_OUT { ... } tc_in; 
out TC_OUT { ... } tc_out;
```

So, tesselation control shader called once for every vertex. Does it mean that tc_in must be not array but single variable. I'm not really sure about that because of sneaky gl_InvocationID.

Then things become tough. Tessellation evaluation shader. Something tells me that evaluation shader should take interface block as array.

```
in TC_OUT { ... } te_in[];
out TE_OUT { ...  } te_out[];
```

Moving to geometry shader. Geometry shader takes multiple vertices, so, definitely array interface block.

```
in TE_OUT  { ... } gs_in[];
out vec3 random_variable;
...
random_variable = gs_in[whatever_index];
```

Seems legit for me, but data didn't come to fragment shader.

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tessellation control shaders take the vertices of a patch as modify them in some way, so their input and output is

```
in VS_OUT { ... } tc_in[]; 
out TC_OUT { ... } tc_out[];
```

The control shader gets called for every patch vertex (see which one by using `gl_InvocationID`), so you usually don't need any loops to implement it.

Tessellation evaluation shaders take these modified vertices and output a *single vertex* per invocation, thus we have

```
in TC_OUT { ... } te_in[];
out TE_OUT { ...  } te_out;
```

Geometry shaders take multiple vertices and may output a different number of vertices, but these are constructed explicitly using `EmitVertex` and `EmitPrimitive`, so there is only one output element that has to be filled before each call of `EmitVertex`:

```
in TE_OUT { ... } gs_in[];
out GS_OUT { ... } gs_out;
```

But don't forget to set `glPosition` in your geometry shader, otherwise OpenGL won't know where to place your vertices.

The interpolated values of `gs_out` are then passed to the fragment shader.

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of help. If you want some examples, when I first used tessellation shaders, [this article](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=48) helped me understand the concepts and implementation.